# Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) footprint near the Kaaba

Tags: history, kaabah, prophet-ibrahim

Here is a picture of Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) footprint near the Kaabah

[image]

Is there any evidence that is definitely footprint of Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH)?

Comment: I recently went to the ka'aba and saw the footprint. It seemed identical to the picture but I couldn't get a really close image of it because of the glass shield covering the footprint. A beautiful piece of history.

Answer (score 5):

I am unable to validate the authenticity of this picture. However, it has been reported by the sahabi Anas ibn Malik that the prophet Ibrahim's footprints had already been worn out (from people touching it) in his time. This was 1400 years ago, so I doubt that there are any of the original markings left in this day and age.

Anas bin Malik's report is mentioned in *Tafsir Ibn Katheer*, specifically in the commentary on Al Baqarah 2:125. It is in page 417 of [this PDF version](http://ia600301.us.archive.org/29/items/tqatqa/tqa1.pdf) (Arabic), or [here for an English translation](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=310#1).

Comment: I am not talking about authenticity of the picture. I meant how they can be sure that footprint near the Kaabah is definitely Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) .

Comment: The report by Anas bin Malik denies the *existence* of footprints on the stone in Maqam Ibrahim. So there are *no* footprints that we need to question.

Answer (score 2):

Ayah [Al Baqarah 125](http://quran.com/2:125) says that the foot print is Ibrahim alai's

> And [mention] when We made the House a place of return for the people and [a place of] security. **And take, [O believers], from the standing place of Abraham a place of prayer.** And We charged Abraham and Ishmael, [saying], "Purify My House for those who perform Tawaf and those who are staying [there] for worship and those who bow and prostrate [in prayer]."

Comment: try posting you answer with refrence

Answer (score 0):

Rahaman Ali is not providing archaeological evidence and saying nonesense.this is pertinent trick of Christian missionaries.recently our brothers refuted this lie,call of monotheism.com,and wiki-himyar,refuting the lie of Patricia crone_amal roubi.answering christianity-paran is mecca.it is ridiculous to deny the prophecy and existence of khane kaaba while chasing the ghost of second temple.also the Jews of himyar themselves confirms that kaaba was indeed created by prophet Ibrahim.

Answer (score -1):

There is simple ideology of human that they make their houses according to thier height . It is written in different books that Adam was 90 feet. With the passage of time Allah reduce the height of human. If you go indepth wisdom and compare height with Adam and Ibrahim. Ibrahim might be shorter but taller than Current human. There are some reason that he might be 30 or 40 feet high:
1. Height of kaba (human make building according to height). 
2. Door of kaba (normally door are made by their body size or shorter than their own size)
3. Every year traveling  from Palestine to Mecca.

Comment: Your answer would be more profitable if you could add some references to support your claims. Please consider reading http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -5):

According to the Archaeological & Biblical evidence it has been proved that neither Prophet Ibrahim even been to that part of the world nor the Kaba or Macca ever existed in His Time.A complete false story of the history.

Comment: This site about Islam and Islamic view. Better answer contains Islamic view. "Biblical evidence"? Even though you want to give an answer from Biblical view or any other view, you should put evidence in your answer.

Comment: Where are the evidence? Whatever you say here it should be with complete reference